# Expect: ^ does not work in a regular expression describing the command prompt of different Cisco devices

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

I am currently optimizing an expect script to gather information from different types of Cisco devices and have a rest problem in the area of regular expressions. Many thanks for your kind help upfront.

Background/issue: Cisco Nexus devices use "#" and "# " in command output which impacts the script logic which uses the same characters to recognize the command prompt before sending the next command.

I could solve most issues by using this more specific definition of command prompt:

```
set prompt {([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
```

and then in the script:

```
expect -re $prompt
send "$cmd\r"
```

Now I wanted to make this regular expression even more specific,
"Start of the line, then the prompt"
by adding a carret "^" at the beginning of the regular expression, but this fails and the script runs always into timeout before sending the next cmd.

```
set prompt {(^[A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
```

this also fails

```
set prompt {^([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
```

In the logfile I see that the command prompt is prepended by CR (^M, 0x0d).

Even more curious, this works still without running into timeout, so yes there is a CR in front of the Cisco CLI prompt:

```
set prompt {[\x0d]([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
```

But not that when using the "^"

```
set prompt {^[\x0d]([A-Z,a-z,0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
```

When using less to browse through the logfile I see this:

```
^MDevice123# term len 0^M
^MDevice123# show inventory^M
```

Hexdump shows between end of the line and new line with the prompt:

```
0d 0d 0a 0d (CR CR LF CR)
```

Any clue whats going wrong with my goal, to make the regular expression for command prompt more specific by describing the prompt from the beginning up to the end of a line ?

Answer (score 2):

`^` would match the beginning of the *buffer*, not just the beginning of the line.

Since expect is built on Tcl, you can use [Tcl regex syntax](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) to indicate that you want `^` to match the empty string after any newline:

```
set prompt {(?n)^[[:alnum:]]+[%#>$]\s?$}
# ..........^^^^
```

Notes:

- in a bracket expression, using a comma means you want to match a comma as well. Instead of `[A-Z,a-z,0-9]` you want `[A-Za-z0-9]` to match letters or number, or use a character class as shown above.
- I suspect you don't need to capture the  bits you parenthesized.

---

Expanding on the last point, when you do this:

```
set prompt {([A-Za-z0-9]+)(%|#|>|\\$)[\\ ]?$}
expect -re $prompt
```

Assume for now that it works as intended. Assume also that your prompt looks like:

```
myHostname1234>
```

After the `expect`, expect will save the captured parts of the regex in the `expect_out` array:

- `$expect_out(0,string)` will contain the text matched by the regex
- `$expect_out(1,string)` will contain the letters and numbers captured by "([A-Za-z0-9]+)", in this case "myHostname1234"
- `$expect_out(2,string)` will contain the prompt symbol captured by "(%|#|>|\$)", in this case ">"

I suspect you don't use the `expect_out` variable in your code, so there's no need to get expect to go to the trouble of storing the matched text. I suspect you really don't care what the prompt symbol is.

I know that parentheses are required to group parts of the regex. However, if you don't need to remember the matched text, you can use `(?:subpattern)` to get the grouping behaviour without the remembering behaviour.

The `expect_out` array contains other stuff too. Read the expect man page for all the details.

Comment: Great, many thanks for taking the time, Glenn, I will try it out and report back to you. And .. sorry I do not understand what exactly you mean by "I suspect you don't need to capture the bits you parenthesized." Could you kindly detail ?

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work (set prompt {(?n)^[[:alnum:]]+[%#>$]\s?$}) runs also into timeout.

Comment: This works and makes my prompt definition more compact: set prompt {[[:alnum:]]+[%#>$]\s?$} but is still missing integration of "beginning of line" (^) to make prompt definition more specific.